# Bootstrap-select dropdown option to be include when using GET in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

So I am trying to make a product page of sorts where you have a drop down menu for an item and a button to add it to your cart. Right now I have the products valued fetched from a MySQL database and loop through all the values to create the product tables. The dropdown menu is populated from the MySQL database as well.

What I am trying to do is, using PHP's GET function, have the value that the user selects from the dropdown box to show up when the user clicks the "Add to Cart" button. Ideally I was gonna have a variable, $x in this case, and have it set to default as a value of 1. Then if the user changes the value of the drop down (select picker) it would then updated the $x variable to hold the new amount for that product. Then when the user clicks the add to cary button, it would execute with the ID of the product, followed by the amount.

IE) addtocart.php?id=12&amount=3

I am not exactly sure how to approach this, I thought about listening to the JS event when it is clicked as bootstrap-select has documentation on it https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events , but I still have no idea how to get the value of the dropdown box to my addtocart.php.

Below I added the code for the dropdown box, as well as a bunch of JS scripts I tried to use to see if they were ever called. None of them were called to my knowledge, and I can't exactly figure out why either, but if I can find a way to do this without JS that would be preferable as I know JS is client side and PHP is server.

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

```html
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            if ($counter % 3 == 0){
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">';
            }
            $counter++;
            echo '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">';
            echo '<div class="card-header">';
            echo ' <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">'.$r['name'].'</h4>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="card-body">';
            echo '<img class="rounded-circle" src="'.$r['image'].'" alt="'.$r['name'].'" width="140" height="140">';

            echo '<div>';
            echo '<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-info" data-width="50%">';
            echo '<option value="1"><h1>$'.$r[price_1].' @ 1</h1></option>';
            echo '<option value="2"><h3>$'.$r[price_2].' @ 2</h3></option>';
            echo '<option value="3"><h3>$'.$r[price_3].' @ 3</h3></option>';
            echo '<option value="4"><h3>$'.$r[price_4].' @ 4</h3></option>';
            echo '<option value="5"><h3>$'.$r[price_5].' @ 5</h3></option>';
            echo '<option value="6"><h3>$'.$r[price_6].' @ 6</h3></option>';
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<p class="card-text">'.$r['description'].'</p>';

            //Help here, trying to get the value from the selected value into the $x variable.

            echo '<p><a href="addtocart.php?id='.$r[id].'&amount='.$x.'" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary" role="button">Addd to Cart</a></p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
         }
```

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            style: 'btn-info',
            size: 4
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').on('click', function () {
            var p1 = "suc1";
            alert($(this).val());
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
            var p1 = "suc2";
            var selected = []
            selected = $('.selectpicker').val()
            console.log(selected); //Get the multiple values selected in an array
            console.log(selected.length); //Length of the array
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
            alert("Hi");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change link to a button (I used 'cart-button' class)

```
<p><button data-rid="<? $r['id']; ?>" class="cart-button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary" type="button">Add to Cart</button></p>
```

I added [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute to your button to hold the 'id' variable

JS will grab the selected option and the id then send the user to the location.
javascript:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".cart-button", function () {
        var selected = $('.selectpicker').val();
        var rid = $(this).data("rid");
        location.href = "addtocart.php?id=" + rid + "&amount=" + selected;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about changing both over to use JS. What scripts and stuff would I need to include as I hadn't been able to get any of the JS for those buttons to work?

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation.  You definitely need jQuery (https://jquery.com/) Make sure you have the "cart-button" class on the button.  Check console log for more info.